# My indian flapshell turtle has developed blisters like appearrance on its shell..its squishy to touch..its been one week .its activity seems normal

Tags: turtles

[image: activity]

My resuced indain flapshell turtle has developed burnt like blisters apperance on its shell we used to keep it  inside the well..its activity,apetite seems normal as before..i used to remove it from the well every week for basking purpose..and thats when i observed it..please help me to treat it before i release it into its natural habitat..

Comment: Does the well where you keep the turtle have sun protection like a roof that offers shade? I can only speculate, but this might be sunburn. The turtle must be able to leave the water whenever it wants to (taking it out once a week isn't enough) and it must be able to move into sunny or shaded areas on its own.